# VBA to check if a shared field exists between 2 different tables?

Tags: vba, ms-access, scripting

I have 2 tables "A" and "B" in an Access Database.

There's a column in A called "AID" with an ID number, and there's a column in B called "BID" with an ID number.

Also, there's a column in A called "OBE" (for obsolete). OBE is a boolean True/False data type.

I want to write a VBA procedure that iterates through each ID number in AID and checks if it exist in BID. If an ID number in AID doesn't exist in BID, I want OBE to be set to "True" for that row.

I plan to implement this code into a button on a form.

I think I have the right idea below but I am unfamiliar with VBA/Access syntax.

Edit (additional context):
One of the reasons why I have it as arrays is because BID isn't just an ID, it's a long title that contains the ID somewhere inside of it. The ID exists somewhere in BID after a sequence of words, so basically I was planning to additionally use the "left()" and "right()" functions, pin-pointing the ID, then creating each element of BID_array one-by-one in a for-loop.

```
Public Function
    dim AID_array as array
    dim BID_array as array
    dim AID_length as integer
    dim BID_length as integer
    isin as boolean

    AID_array = A.AID
    BID_array = B.BID
    AID_length = length(AID_array)
    BID_length = length(BID_array)

    for i = 1:AID_length
        isin = false
        for j = 1:BID_length
            if AID_array(i) = BID_array(j) then
                isin = true
            endif
        next j
        if isin = false then
            A.OBE(i) = true
        end if
    next i
End Function
```

Comment: Just use an update query. Left outer join AID to BID if BID is null then OBE TRUE else FALSE.

Comment: None of that code is needed. Build UPDATE SQL with Access query builder as described by @Warcupine and save. Then manually run or use code to run object or construct SQL statement in code and run that.

Comment: Ok but one of the reasons why I have it as a macro and arrays is because BID isnt just an ID, its a long title that contains the ID somewhere inside of it. The ID exists somewhere in BID after a sequence of words, so basically I was planning to additionally use the "left()" and "right()" functions, pin-pointing the ID, then creating each element of BID_array from the results one-by-one in a for-loop. I hope this makes sense.

Given this would a "update query" work for this? @Warcupine

Comment: A long term solution might be to add a column (ID) in Table B to store IDs and use an `UPDATE` query to populate it with the extracted ID (since you know how to grab it). Run update queries on OBE after that using a `SELECT` subquery of [Table A].AID in the where clause of [Table B].ID.

Comment: Okay, I had to re-read question. Maybe this code is needed or maybe build queries that extract the ID values then build another query that joins on the extracted ID values. Edit question to show sample data as text tables. BTW, you say 'macro' but this is actually VBA. Macros in Access are very different.

Comment: And exactly what is the issue with code? You tested it? Is there error, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: I would really just like to know what the syntax is for referencing tables, fields, and cells in fields in vba...

Answer (score 0):

Try this procedure:

```
Private Sub cmdTesting_Click()
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim sql As String
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from A Left Join B On A.AID = B.BID", dbOpenDynaset, dbInconsistent)
rst.MoveFirst
Do While Not (rst.EOF)
    If IsNull(rst("BID")) Then
        rst.Edit
        rst("OBE") = True
        rst.Update
    End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: Instead of looping recordset, could just execute an UPDATE action SQL.

Comment: If you dont mind, can you explain what's going on here a little bit? What's a recordset and Dynaset? @hamed nasr

Comment: A recordset is a database structure that holds a numbwe of records and handled in VBA
dynaset is a type of recordset that is dynamic in nature and stays synchrorized with data source.